# Send a private message to a user tag

Tags: discord.js

Is there a way to send a direct message to a `user` via user tag?

For example: `Username#0000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a `user` object via `tag` using the [`.find()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
message.client.users.cache.find(user => user.tag === 'Username#0000').send('This is a DM')
```